# How to correct TomcatFailure

Tags: tomcat

In Most of the ServletPrograms I found the following error which says:

[image: ![Tomcat7Failure]

> Can anyone guide me how should I correct this:
>   @Edit1:

**NOTE**

This problem does not occur sometimes when I switch my workspace and import the same project
@Edit2:

Complete StackTrace:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringDaoMvc]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringDaoMvc]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
at  org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(Web AnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 20 more

Aug 07, 2016 1:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.  Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 07, 2016 1:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 07, 2016 1:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Aug 07 13:13:58 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-  INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 358 ms
Aug 07, 2016 1:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Aug 07 13:13:58 IST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -  Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1063 ms
Aug 07, 2016 1:13:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ServletChainInclude]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ServletChainInclude]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name SendRedirect3
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3320)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3299)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

 Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1 142)
at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

 Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Aug 07 13:13:58 IST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Aug 07, 2016 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Aug 07 13:13:58 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: can you post the complete log? it seems like the log is not complete

Comment: StackTrace is not complete, yet. can you post all? like in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841870/a-child-container-failed-during-start

Comment: @victorsosa Done Editing

Comment: which tomcat version it is?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7

Comment: exact version please

Comment: @victorsosa 7.0.67

Comment: I see now in you logs this 'Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' so the spring jars is missing and also 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name SendRedirect3' there is a problem with the name of that servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` Check in your current IDE if the dependency is included in intellij this can be achieved by pressing the *shift+ctrl+alt+s* keys.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`. Make sure the necessary jars are in your application or server classpath.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` actually suggest that you don't have `spring-context-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar` in your project's lib folder or the version is different.

Answer (score 1):

I see now in you logs this `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext` so the spring jars is missing and also `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name SendRedirect3` there is a problem with the name in the mapping of that servlet named SendRedirect3.